# How can I add a class to an element if the text is the same?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two different `div`s:

```html
<div class="first-div">this is the same text</div>
<div class="second-div">this is the same text</div>
```

Is it possible to detect if the text in the both `div`s is the same, then add class to the second `div`?

```html
<div class="second-div newclass">this is the same text</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `if($("first-div").text() == $("second-div").text() == )` m?

Comment: exactly! if the text of `.first-div` equals the text of the `.second-div` then add class to `.second-div`

Comment: [Create a minimal reproducable exampel](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this small program to answer your question :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var div1_text = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var div2_text = document.getElementById("two").value;
  if (div1_text == div2_text) {
    document.getElementById("two").classList.add("class2");
  }
}
```

```css
.class2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="one" class="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
<div id="two" class="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible in pure JS, jQuery is not even needed:

```js
const firstDiv = document.querySelector('.first-div');
const secondDiv = document.querySelector('.second-div');
if (firstDiv.textContent === secondDiv.textContent) {
  secondDiv.className += ' new-class';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

```
document.getElementsByClassName("second-div")[0].className="second-div newclass"
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the divs have the same content, but instead adds `newclass`.

Comment: Ohh ok I didn't understand the question that way.